# How to properly execute a convert command using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, converters, gif

I'm new to Python, so, I'm sorry if my question may seems dumb.

I'm trying to convert GIF files to APNG using [this tool](https://github.com/vertopal/vertopal-cli).

As it says in the bottom of [this page](https://www.vertopal.com/en/convert/gif-to-apng), to convert GIF to APNG you must execute the following command:

```bash
$ vertopal convert GIF_INPUT_FILE --to apng
```

It works fine when I run the command in the terminal, but I cannot implement it in my Python code.

Here is my code:

```py
import subprocess

discord_sticker_converter = subprocess.call("vertopal convert funny cat.gif --to apng")
print(discord_sticker_converter)
```

This is what is printed in the output:

```
usage: vertopal [options] <command> [<args>]
vertopal: error: unrecognized arguments: cat.gif
2
```

How should I call the convert command properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's talk about your command:

```py
"vertopal convert funny cat.gif --to apng"
```

The name "funny cat.gif" has space in it. `subprocess` calls `shlex.split()` to split this string into a list of string tokens and the result is:

```py
>>> shlex.split("vertopal convert funny cat.gif --to apng")
['vertopal', 'convert', 'funny', 'cat.gif', '--to', 'apng']
```

As you can see, the file name is broken into 2 tokens: "funny" and "cat.gif". That is why it failed. To fix this situation, you need to properly quote your file name:

```py
>>> shlex.split("vertopal convert 'funny cat.gif' --to apng")
['vertopal', 'convert', 'funny cat.gif', '--to', 'apng']
```

The function `subprocess.call()` is flexible: it can take a single string and try to split it, or it can take a list of strings. That means both of these will work:

```py
subprocess.call("vertopal convert 'funny cat.gif' --to apng")
subprocess.call(['vertopal', 'convert', 'funny cat.gif', '--to', 'apng'])
```

The first form is more compact and is what you would do in the terminal. The second form is more explicit. Which form to use is your choice. As for me, I will choose the second form because the Zen of python said

> Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: This was a really good information to know.

Answer (score 3):

you need to make it as list and run it

```
import subprocess

command = ["vertopal", "convert", "funny cat.gif", "--to", "apng"]
discord_sticker_converter = subprocess.call(command)
print(discord_sticker_converter)
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason we should send a list?

Comment: @FireStarter the reason is you can Handling Spaces, for security reason, and No Shell ParsingBy using lists, command execution is safer and more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the platform on which you run this script, you may want to write your command as a list of strings instead of just a string:

```py
discord_sticker_converter = subprocess.call(
    ["vertopal", "convert", "funny cat.gif", "--to", "apng"]
)
```

[Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) advise to use list of strings instead of just strings for a variety of reasons, one of which being that argument parsing is not a trivial problem, especially when arguments contain space characters (which is your case).

In your implementation, `funny` and `cat.gif` would be interpreted as two different arguments. Fusing them in a list of strings allows to explicitly say that `funny cat.gif` is one argument altogether.

Comment: Sorry, but it still gives the same error.

Comment: My bad, I missed the true error in your implementation. The updated answer should hopefully make things clearer :)